# Convert encryption logic from JAVA to DART

Tags: java, dart, encryption

I have an Android application (Built over JAVA) to be converted to Flutter. There is an encryption function and a decryption function in JAVA which I am looking to convert to DART.

However, it seems like something is missing in the conversion and therefore, it is not encrypting starting few characters in the string and therefore, when decrypting back, it does not bring the correct data back.

Below is the JAVA code in use.

```
public static String encrypt(Context ctx, String requestString) {
        String encryptString = "";

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
            byte[] b = 'SOME16CHARSTRING'.getBytes("UTF-8");
            int len = b.length;
            if (len > keyBytes.length)
                len = keyBytes.length;

            System.out.println("Length - " + len);
            System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(requestString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            encryptString = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            GlobalMethods.SendErrorReport(ctx, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptString;
    }
```

And the converted DART code is as below.

```
String encryptAES(String plainTextString) {
    try {
        final key = Key.fromUtf8('SOME16CHARSTRING');
        final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
        final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc, padding: "PKCS7"));
        final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainTextString, iv: iv);
        final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

        return encrypted.base64;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error while encoding String : $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Anything which I can correct here ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In Java you use the key as IV (which is generally insecure), in Dart you apply a zero IV (all 16 bytes 0). To get the same ciphertext with both codes (the same key and plaintext assumed) the same IV must be used.

Comment: By the way, for encryption the line `encrypter.decrypt()` is not necessary, because it decrypts.

Comment: That is right @Topaco. Thanks a lot. That was the overlook. I changed the IV to  derive from the KEY just as in JAVA and it worked perfect.

Thanks for your help.